# ActionMode style override the main ActionBar in my android app

Tags: java, android, xml, android-styles, android-toolbar

I'm building an Android app with AppCompat Theme but I have a problem to set my ActionMode theme in my app.
I'm trying to add a new style for this but it seems override the main actionbar and I don't know why...

This is the main Actionbar:

[image]

When I try to copy a text...

[image]

This is my actionbar layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay"
    app:popupTheme="@style/PopupMenuStyle">
```

And finally, this is my style.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#808080</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/Spinner.spnItem</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/Spinner.spnItemDropDown</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/primarycolor</item>
        <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/ActionModeStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarThemeOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#fff</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">#fff</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/primarycolor</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PopupMenuStyle">
        <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionModeStyle">
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/primarycolor</item>
    </style>
```

I'm loosing my mind...

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this for "ActionModeStyle", should work:

```
<style name="ActionModeStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
        <item name="background">@color/primarycolor</item>
</style>
```

Instead of "android:colorBackground> you should use only "background".
And I think it is better to define an parent.